# Victim of revenge downvoting of questions

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

I have recently been the victim of revenge downvoting.  I think the evidence is pretty clear:

[image]

Except for the Roslyn one, these are all ancient questions.  I don't often get downvotes on questions, but it happens from time to time.  The fact that:

1. They came so close together
2. Yet were cunningly separated by a short time interval
3. Were old questions
4. Were questions (and therefore free to the downvoter) in contrast to answers
5. I (and I assume most people) do not ever get questions downvoted en masse

I believe this is pernicious behavior.  I hate to even bring it up, but at the minimum, attention should be brought to tactics such as these.  Do I have any recourse?  So far, this has been about 48 hours.

Comment: 48 hours probably means it didn't catch by the automated script; best to flag for moderator attention and explain the situation.

Comment: @Pëkka, thanks, will do.